# Why does stdarg.h have a macro « __va_size »?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I was looking for some code about  macros, and I found a code like this, for the macro « va_start » :

```
#define __va_argsiz(t)  \
    (((sizeof(t) + sizeof(int) - 1) / sizeof(int)) * sizeof(int))
#define va_start(ap, pN)    \
    ((ap) = ((va_list) (&pN) + __va_argsiz(pN)))
```

I would like to know what is the goal of « __va_argsiz »  function exactly. Is it alignment limitations ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense without giving us details of the platform where you found this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both alignment, and the default type promotion rules in C.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is used to compute the start of the variable argument list, based on the size of the first argument. The first argument is the required normal one, i.e. for `printf()` it would be the pointer to the formatting string.

Answer (score 1):

This is used for [variable length arguments](http://c-faq.com/varargs/index.html). For example `printf` uses such a variable length argument list. `__va_argsiz` computes the size of the list and `va_start` determines the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

No "limitation", *implementation*. `__va_argsiz` ***rounds up*** the `sizeof(t)`, for a type `t`, in multiples of `sizeof(int)`. That is needed because the uknown arguments that are being passed on the call stack as part of varargs function call protocol are automatically aligned and allocated the space in multiples of `sizeof(int)` (apparently, on your platform), and have to be retrieved properly from there.

See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/.